# Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function error when using JNA with C++

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, jna

This is the code I used for the native-lib.cpp file.

```
extern "C" {



char *libName() {
    return (char *) "My Math Shared Library";
}


}
```

I used this whenever implementing it in the main activity file

```
package com.example.tenealaspencer.example;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.sun.jna.Native;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //loading native library
    static {
        Native.register(MainActivity.class, "native-lib");
    }

    //native methods signatures

    public native String libName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //calling native methods

        System.out.println(libName());
    }
}
```

I changed the dependencies to compile as JNA in the gradle(module), but I am still getting this error message.

Comment: Please post the relevant pieces of your gradle script. Actually, the error may be coming from the Android Studio integration only, in which case it can be ignored.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to add @SuppressWarnings("JniMissingFunction")
before my class. I have android studio 3.0 and for whatever reason it doesn't recognize JNA methods.

Comment: As far as I know, AS has never been able to recognize JNA methods.